# Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc.so'

Tags: php, pdo, cpanel, whm

After upgrade server to AlmaLinux v8.9.0 STANDARD standard Version 116.0.11; old PHP versions remved, so i have a website was working using php 5.6
now i can't login to website admin panel with PHP 7.2; This issue appear

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc.so' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_odbc.so (/lib64/libltdl.so.7: file too short), /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_odbc.so.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

[See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLmKZ.png)

I tried commands:

yum provides */libodbc.so.2
yum reinstall libodbc.so.2

But theissue still

Comment: `dnf install php-odbc`

Comment: Did you install ODBC?